# Problemas com Adapter de ListView

Tags: android

Possuo uma Activity que tem uma `ListView`. Os itens da `ListView` eu mesmo construi. Coloquei um `EditText` e preciso fazer um evento `setOnClickListener` nele. Mas o correto seria fazer isso na Activity principal e não na classe Adapter. Tenho o Adpter declarado na Activity principal, mas como faço pra acionar esse evento?

Codigo do adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ExclusaoItem item = itens.get(position);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_exclusao,null);

    TextView ref = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_ref_exclusao);
    ref.setText(String.valueOf(item.getProduto()));

    TextView tamanho = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_tamanho_exclusao);
    tamanho.setText(String.valueOf(item.getTamanho()));

    TextView situacao = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_situacao_exclusao);
    if(item.getEstoque()==1){
        situacao.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        situacao.setText("Estoque");
    }

    final EditText codBarrasPainel = view.findViewById(R.id.edt_painel_produto);
```

preciso fazer o setOnClickListener no codBarrasPainel que está no final do codigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar o evento como uma interface no Adapter sem ação nenhuma e na Activity você instância ele e coloca a ação desejada.

Adapter:

```
//resto da classe



private ObjetoAdapter.ObjetoOnClickListener objetoOnClickListener;

/**
* interface para clique
*/
public  interface ObjetoOnClickListener{
  public  void onClickObjeto(View view, int idx);
}
```

no evento getView():

```
if (objetoOnClickListener != null){
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    objetoOnClickListener.onClickObjeto(holder.itemView, position);
                }
            });
        }
```

//Activity:

```
/**
     * evento aplicado na interface OnGridMesaClick
     * @return ObjetoAdapter.ObjetoOnClickListener
     */
    private ObjetoAdapter.ObjetoOnClickListener onClickObjeto(){
        return  new ObjetoAdapter.ObjetoOnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClickObjeto(View view, int idx) {
                onGridObjetoClick.onClick(objetos.get(idx));
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: fiz uma rascunho rápido, pode ter alguns erros

Comment: Será que tenho que usar esse código enorme só pra um um setOnClicklistener num campo da lista. Não entendi muito bem, mas vou tentar. Achei que seria mais simples. =(

Comment: É que no adapter você vai criar uma interface, pode pesquisar sobre elas e tentar reduzir na maneira que mais lhe servir.